# Is it possible to add a combiner only on part of the mappers?

Tags: hadoop

I have a use case in which I use MultipleInputs to have different mappers depending on the input path. For some of these mappers, it would be interesting to run a combiner afterwards (before sending o the reducer), for some others it would be a total waste.

Is there a way to set a combiner only for the interesting part of the mappers ?

Comment: How have you setup different mappers dependent on input path?

Comment: MultipleInputs.AddInputPath(...). Is there another way ?